# Can't run my Docker container anymore (error TCP Provider: Error code 0x2749) ever since I installed and created a MSSQLSERVER local instance

Tags: sql-server, docker, mssql-jdbc

I'm currently using Docker Desktop for a project with a shared image of a MSSQL DB, I downloaded the image, ran the container and everything worked fine and dandy.
Yesterday I needed to create a local instance of a DB for another project, I installed Microsoft SQL Server, created the local instance and worked with it.

Today I ran again the Docker container but got an error because I carelessly gave the MSSQL Server and the docker image the same port on localhost, so I changed the port on the MSSQL Server and ran the container again but it keeps giving me this error over and over again:

> 2023-04-14 11:26:36 not ready yet...
>
> 2023-04-14 11:26:36 Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : Login timeout expired.
>
> 2023-04-14 11:26:36 Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : TCP Provider: Error code 0x2749.
>
> 2023-04-14 11:26:36 Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online..

This error is all I get for 3-5 minutes until eventually the container stops, if I try to connect to the DB while the container is running I get this error:

> The TCP/IP connection to the host localhost, port 1433 has failed. Error: "The driver received an unexpected pre-login response. Verify the connection properties and check that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. This driver can be used only with SQL Server 2005 or later.

I'm not sure what to do, I expected the container to work correctly once I changed the port on the MSSQL Server, I've been searching for similar cases and possible solutions but nothing seems to work, (checked firewall, wsl, recreated the container, stopped all local instances) and I'm not sure where should I intervene.

The docker command I've used for the container:

```bash
docker run -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" -e "MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=SomePassword123$" -p 1433:1433 --name [dbName] --hostname [dbName] -d [registryLoginURL]/[imageName]:[imageVersion]
```

Comment: *"so I changed the port on the MSSQL Server"* On which one, the docker image or the localhost? How did you change the port

Comment: I changed it on the local DB via Sql Server Configuration Manager

Comment: Did you solve this issue?